# Store and make available XHR'd data to multiple components in Angular (2/4+)

Tags: angular

I have a backend that I can fetch 'Mission' objects from. I have a class called MissionService.

The angular.io hero tutorial suggests the MissionService should have a getMissions method:

```
getMissions(): Promise<Mission[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.missionsUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json() as Mission[]
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I have multiple components that want to access my missions. The angular.io tutorial seems to suggest I should import the MissionService in their constructors, and do:

```
export class MissionsComponent implements OnInit {

    missions: Mission[];

    constructor(
        private missionService: MissionService
    ){}

    getMissions(): void {
        this.missionService.getMissions()
            .then(missions => {
                this.missions = missions;
                this.doSomething();
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getMissions();
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing, is that this means, every component I want to use my missions in, ends up having its own instance of this.missions, which is potentially different to the this.missions of other components. It also means that I need to wait for the async call to complete every time I want to access my missions in a component. It also means I need to mess around with calling getMissions() in each component.

So, isn't the suggested approach a pretty bad one?

Wouldn't it be better to have a single, global this.missions field? This way, I could programmatically update my missions when I need to (e.g. user clicks refresh button).

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular services are singleton in nature hence You can use another data service to share the data that has to be shared between components. Data service typically has getter and setter methods.ie have a  service that will call the http method and then called the data services to share the data between components if you dont want separate http calls for getting the data .

For ex.

**Data service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UrlHistoryService {
    private urlHistory: string;

    constructor() {
        this.urlHistory = "";
    }

    public setUrlHistoryObj(val: string): void {
        this.urlHistory = val;
    }

    public getUrlHistoryObj(): string {
        return this.urlHistory;
    }

}
```

**Component 1**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UrlHistoryService } from '../shared/service/url-history-store.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'search-movie-list-producer',
    templateUrl: '../../Scripts/app/search-movies/search-movie-list.component.html'
})

export class SearchMovieListProducerComponent {
    constructor(
        private urlHistoryService: UrlHistoryService) {

        this.urlHistoryService.setUrlHistoryObj("/movie/searchMovie");
    }
}
```

and **Component 2**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UrlHistoryService } from '../shared/service/url-history-store.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'search-movie-list-b',
    templateUrl: '../../Scripts/app/search-movies/search-movie-list.component.html'
})

export class SearchMovieListConsumerComponent {
    backUrl: string;

    constructor(
        private urlHistoryService: UrlHistoryService) {

        this.backUrl = this.urlHistoryService.getUrlHistoryObj();
    }
}
```

.In your case in the component make a http cal and call the data service to set the data and use this service in other components to get the shared data.You can read more about this [here](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/angular2-using-data-service-to-communicate-between-components-in-angular2-application/)